# $f(x) = Mid( x-1,(x-3)^2,3-[(x-3)^2]/2 )$ x belongs [1,4] then the greatest value in [1,4]?

Tags: functions

If $f(x) = Mid \{ g(x),h(x),p(x)\}$ means the function which will be second in order when values of the three function at a particular value of $x$ are arranged then for,

$f(x) = Mid\{ x-1,(x-3)^2,3-[(x-3)^2]/2 \},$ $\;\;x\in[1,4]$.

then the greatest value in $[1,4]$ ? I am getting it as $3$... but it's wrong.

$x-1$ from $[1 , 2-root3]$ then  $3-[(x-3)^2]/2$ from $[2-root3 , 3-root2]$ then $(x-3)^2$  from $ [3-root2 , 2]$ then $x-1$  from $[2, 4]$

Comment: are u just posting ur homework? plz show us what u have done.

Comment: i worked out..the function.. let me tell the function

Comment: it should probably be $\sqrt {3}+1$. Check ur points again and [see this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/buxc5e31bf)

Comment: Do I get it right that $\operatorname{mid}(a,b,c)=a+b+c-\max(a,b,c)-\min(a,b,c)$?

Answer (score 1):

The graphs of $x-1$ and $3-\frac{(x-3)^2}2$ intersect when $x^2-4x+1=0$, i.e. at $x=2\pm\sqrt{3}$. 
Conclude that $\sup f=1+\sqrt 3$ from the following

**Claim.** For each $x\in[1,4]$, at least two of the values $x-1$, $(x-3)^2$, $3-\frac{(x-3)^2}2$ are $\le 1+\sqrt 3$.

*Proof:*

- $x-1\le 1+\sqrt 3$ for $x\in[1,2+\sqrt 3]$,
- $(x-3)^2 \le 1+\sqrt3$ for $3-\sqrt{1+\sqrt 3}\le x\le 3+\sqrt{1+\sqrt 3}$, especially for $x\in [3-\sqrt{1+\sqrt 3},4]$
- $3-\frac{(x-3)^2}2 \le1+\sqrt 3$ if $x\ge 2+\sqrt 3$ and also if $x\le 4-\sqrt 3$, i.e. for $x\in [1,4-\sqrt 3]\cup[2+\sqrt 3,4]$

Simple calculations show that $3-\sqrt{1+\sqrt 3}<4-\sqrt 3$, hence the claim. $_\square$